# webapi VS template individual user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created a new project web API with an individual user, but when I go on: http://localhost:51098/api/Account/Register, It returns this error:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",
  "StackTrace": "   in provawebapi.Controllers.AccountController.<Register>d__20.MoveNext() in c:\\users\\passalacqua\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\provawebapi\\provawebapi\\Controllers\\AccountController.cs:riga 331\r\n--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   in System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   in System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   in System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   in System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   in System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   in System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using some class with out creating new instance in the account Controller. Please check that one.

Comment: yes, in debug on register function, modelstate is valid but model is null.. I think that I'm wrong way of passing parameters :(